# Rust: How to hash a string?

Tags: rust, hash, cryptography

I'm trying to create a console application in Rust where you have to enter a password to access the rest of the file, so I wanted to ensure that you can't just read the file to find the password, so I wanted to store the password as a hash, so its (improbably) irreversable.

I looked up hashing in Rust, but they seem to be only usable with structs, while I'm trying to insert a String. Is a struct the only way to be able to do this?

Comment: https://docs.rs/password-hash/0.1.1/password_hash/

Comment: so its (probably) irreversable ? no ?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk You linked to an older version of the cargo, and the documentation of this cargo is confusing, only listing functions with little to no explanation.

Comment: @Stargateur what I meant is that someone would be unlikely be able to reverse the password in the file, like a hash.

Comment: Why hash? Your use case suggests a need for scrypt or similar to generate a decryption key.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Not for this situation! Example, if a user were to attempt to open a file, they'd input the password, and it'll be hashed and then compared. I'm not trying to RETRIEVE, im measuring if the inputted password is correct

Comment: But they could open the file without using your program, right? Or they could use a password database or rainbow tables if you don't use a memory-hard hash.

Comment: Sounds like you’re using the wrong tool. What would prevent a user from opening the file in another program, that doesn’t check for that hash, and access all the content? Sounds like you need encryption, not password verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in Hash class in Rust is designed to process data for the purpose of entry into a HashMap or HashSet.  This isn't suitable for password verification.

If you want to perform password verification, you should use a password hash like Argon2id or scrypt.  You can find these in the `argon2` and `scrypt` crates.  Password hashes always take bytes, so you will want to access your String as a `&[u8]`.  The `password_hash` crate provides traits you can use to turn these into a serialized password.

If your goal is to encrypt the remainder of the file with the password, then you should use one of the bindings to NaCl.  This library has primitives that are designed to be secure.  You would use the password hash functionality with a random salt to generate a key, and then use that as the key input to  a secret box with a random nonce.  There are other ways to do this, but unless you are well versed in cryptography, using NaCl is a smart choice since it is harder to misuse.

Answer (score 0):

using this:

```
argon2="0.5"
```

in your function

```
use argon2::{password_hash::{rand_core::OsRng, SaltString}, PasswordHasher};

pub async fn create_hash(password:String){
    // OsRng OS's random number generator 
    let salt=SaltString::generate(OsRng);
    let argon2=argon2::Argon2::default();
    let password_hash=argon2.hash_password(password.as_bytes(), &salt).unwrap();
    password_hash
}
```